# How to update mysql column with another value from another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

How to replace the value in 'projectId' column with project name assuming there is another table with name 'project' and two tables are related on the number mentioned after ':' in 'projectId' column of employee output.

```
> select * from employee;
+----+-----------+
| id | projectId |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | project:1 |
+----+-----------+
```

Desired output :

```
+----+-----------------------+
| id | projectId             |
+----+-----------------------+
|  1 | project:internProject |
+----+-----------------------+
```

Steps required:

> extract the integer [done]

```
update employee SET projectId = substring_index(projectId,':', -1);
```

> update the projectID with name [not sure :( ]

```
update employee SET projectId = concat('project:', select projectName from projects where projects.projectID = employee.projectId);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need parenthesis around your subrequest.

```
update employee e
set projectId = concat('project:',
                       (select projectName
                        from projects
                        where projectId = substring_index(e.projectId, ':', -1)));
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
UPDATE employee e, projects p
SET e.projectId = CONCAT('project:',p.projectName)
WHERE substring_index(e.projectId,':', -1) = p.projectID
```

Is **project:** a constant or does it change? If so you need to take it over from employee

Comment: Thanks for the answer , project is constant

Answer (score 0):

Use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` and `JOIN`.

**Query**

```
update employee e
join project p
on e.id = p.id
set e.pid = concat(substring_index(e.pid, ':', 1), ':',
               p.pname);
```